# Hive UDF to return multiple colunm output

Tags: hive, hiveql, hive-udf

How create a UDF which take a String return multiple  Strings ?
The UDF so far I have seen could only give one output. How to get multiple feilds as output from a UDF ?

Simplest would be implementation of name -> FirstName, LastName.
Not looking for alternate solution to split names, but looking for API / UDF which would help implement such needs .

Lets Say nameSplitteris my UDF

> Select  age,nameSplitter(name) as firstName,LastName from myTable;
>
> InPut

```
    ****Input****
------------------------
    Age | Name
------------------------
    24  | John Smit
    13  | Sheldon Cooper
-------------------------
```

> OutPut

```
    ****Out put ****
-----------------------------------
    Age | First Name  | Last Name
-----------------------------------
    24  | John        | Smit
    13  | Sheldon     | Cooper
-----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [split()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) function, it splits strinng around regexp pattern and returns an array:

```
select age, 
       NameSplitted[0] as FirstName,
       NameSplitted[1] as LastName
  from  
    (
    select age, 
           split(Name,' +') as NameSplitted 
     from myTable
    )s;
```

Or just `select age, split(Name,' +')[0] FirstName, split(Name,' +')[0] LastName from myTable;`

Pattern `' +'` means one or more spaces.

Also if you have three words names or even longer and you want to split only first word as a name and everything else as last name, or using more complex rule, you can use regexp_extract function like in this example:

```
hive> select regexp_extract('Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart', '^(.*?)(?: +)(.*)$', 1);
OK
Johannes
Time taken: 1.144 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select regexp_extract('Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart', '^(.*?)(?: +)(.*)$', 2);
OK
Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart
Time taken: 0.692 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Pattern here means: the beginning of the string '^', first capturing group consisting of any number of characters `(.*?)`, non-capturing group consisting of any number of spaces `(?: +)`, last capturing group consisting of any number of characters greedy `(.*)`, and `$` means the end of the string

Comment: Sir, How to have a UDF, which returns two feilds is the question, 
not alternate way to do this.

Comment: @user2458922 Sorry, I got you in a wrong way. Maybe this code would be useful and you can start implementing your own UDF: https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFSplit.java - this is split() UDF code, you can modify the code and build your own UDF. Try to implement your own UDF and ask questions about implementation.